# Rewrite URL to a friendly URL in PHP builtin-in server (XAMPP)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm creating a CMS project, and i'm having some problem trying to make urls more friendly in a page called PostContainer.php

My goal is, when the user access this url: https://localhost/ProjetoCMS/PostContainer.php?slug=post-numero-01-teste-01&id=1 , the url that is showed up is: https://localhost/posts/post-numero-01-teste-01 because me php code in the PostContainer.php page gets the slug and the id via GET and query my database to have access to the correct result:
My PostContainer.php file:

```
<?php
//database connection
require('./ConexaoSql.php');
//verify if slug an id where sent
if (isset($_GET['slug']) && isset($_GET['id'])) {
    //Select the post from the database
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `controle-de-posts` WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $post = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  
    $url = "/posts/" . $_GET['slug'];
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== $url) {
      header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
      header("Location: $url");
      exit();
    }
  } else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
  }
  ?>
  
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo $post['titulo']; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/PostContainer.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <?php require_once("./Header.php"); ?>
    </header>
    <div class="corpo-texto">
      <div class="postcontainer-area">
        <!--Title -->
        <h1><?php echo $post['titulo']; ?></h1>

        <!--Post text-->
        <p><?php echo $post['texto_post']; ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

But when the file loads it shows me "File not found" like the server is requesting this url: "https://localhost/posts/post-numero-01-teste-01" which did not exists, ok, but i'm using .htaccess to redirect all requests to ^posts/([^/]+)/?$ to the file PostContainer.php?slug=$1&id=$2

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]+)/?$ /PostContainer?slug=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

But still showing me the that there is no found file.
How can i fix that? How can i make the user see the friendly url when he access:  https://localhost/ProjetoCMS/PostContainer.php?slug=post-numero-01-teste-01&id=1
But, showing the content of the original URL

I already try searching a lot in the web about .htaccess and already enabled rewrite_modules in apache.conf

Already enabled AllowOverride

Already tried to use a test rule like:

```
Rewriterule ^/test example.com.br [NC, L]
```

Comment: `https://localhost/posts/post-numero-01-teste-01` - where is the "id"? Please clarify what URL you are actually linking to?

Comment: You mention "builtin-in server (XAMPP)" - but XAMPP (ie. Apache) is not the "built-in" server? By "built-in" I assume you mean the webserver that is literally built-in to PHP? (Some users get confused by this and think they are using Apache, but in fact are using the built-in server that does not use `.htaccess` files.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]+)/(\d+)$ /PostContainer?slug=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

This will redirect any url of format :

`https://localhost/posts/post-numero-01-teste-01/1` to `https://localhost/PostContainer?slug=post-numero-01-teste-01&id=1`